# Ideal generated by a set of polynomials $X^{a/b}$ where each monomial having $a$ and not having $b$

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, ideals, boolean-algebra, reference-works

Let

$$\mathcal R=\mathbb Z_2[x_1,\dots,x_n]/\langle x_1^2-x_1,\dots,x_n^2-x_n\rangle.$$

I want to learn ideal arithmetics to deal with polynomials of the forms such as

1. Consider a set of polynomials 
   $$X^{a/b}=\{ x^\gamma \mid a\in \gamma, b\not\in\gamma,\gamma\in\mathcal R \}$$ 
   where $x^\gamma$ is a monomial like $x_1x_2x_5x_a$ such that each monomial has an indeterminate $a$ and each monomial does not have an indeterminate $b$. Consider the ideal $I^{a/b}$ that is a set of polynomials where each monomial has an indeterminate $a$ and each monomial does not have an indeterminate $b.$
2. Now consider 
   $$X^{A\backslash B}=\{ x^\gamma \mid \gamma\in A, \gamma\not\in B,\gamma\in\mathcal R\}$$
   where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ that is $X^{A\backslash B}$ is a set of all monomials that contains $x_i$ with $i\in A$ and $x_j$ with $j\not\in B$. Then $X^{A\backslash B}$ in fact generates the ideal $I^{A\backslash B}$.

So

**Where can you find books and references on ideal arithmetics dealing with polynomials having the ground ring $\mathcal R$?**

Comment: I find it extremely hard to understand what $X^{a/b}$ and $I^{a/b}$ are (is there a difference between the two ?), could you reformulate the question to make it mort clear ?

Comment: @CaptainLama good question, I don't know yet whether $X^{a/b}$ equals $I^{a/b}$ and can there be a difference in some case? I feel there must be research on this, perhaps in the context of cuts, so hence a reason for the reference request question.

Comment: Yes, but can you be more precise about it ? Is there a ground ring ? What are the indeterminates ? "Consider a set of polynomials" -> what set ? "Considet the ideal $I^{a/b}$ that is a set of polynomials" -> again, what set ? Lots of things in your question are very vague and hard to understand for those who don't know the context (and you're the only one who knows the context).

Comment: @CaptainLama the ground ring added. Is it clear now where I want to learn ideal arithmetics?

Comment: If I understand well $X^{a/b}$ is in fact $X^{a\setminus b}$, where $a,b$ are subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, that is, the set of all monomials which contain at least a variable $x_i$ with $i\in a$ and don't contain any variable $x_j$ with $j\in b$. Then $I^{a\setminus b}$ is the ideal generated by the set $X^{a\setminus b}$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you, updated. I understand this such that $X^{a/b}\subseteq X^{A\backslash B}$ so the case in the comment contains the first case, now labelled as 1.